# Can I get each regex group match count in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the text:

```
There are many kids in the playground. It's about 1 23  45 5;中文等等
```

Here is the Regex Pattern I use `([0-9])|([a-zA-Z])|([\u4e00-\u9fa5])"`
I want to get the three match group count:pattern1 `[0-9]` the number is 6; The `[\u4e00-\u9fa5]` count is 4，Is there possible to calculate that.

I have tried

```
var characterMatch = characterPattern.Matches(content)
```

but I only get the all match count is 49. So, is there possible to get the different part count?

What I expected to get is that the match the `[0-9]` count, match the [a-zA-Z] count

Comment: you can name you groups... (?<group_name>...) and then on the regex result call Groups["group_name"] and count the ones with success

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want to achieve. What is the output that you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression:

```
(?<digit>[0-9])|(?<letter>[a-zA-Z])|(?<ucode>[\u4e00-\u9fa5])
```

in that code:

```
string strRegex = @"(?<digit>[0-9])|(?<letter>[a-zA-Z])|(?<ucode>[\u4e00-\u9fa5])";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"There are many kids in the playground. It's about 1 23  45 5;????";

int digits = 0;
int letters = 0;
int ucode = 0;
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    digits += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["digit"].Value) ? 1 : 0);
    letters += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["letter"].Value) ? 1 : 0);
    ucode += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["ucode"].Value) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

In a single iteration counts all matches.

Note: To test regular expressions on c# online I use http://regexhero.net/tester/ (Silverlight only in IE... O_o)

Comment: Regex pattern without group name is ok, then use `myMatch.Groups[1]`, `myMatch.Groups[2]` etc.

Comment: @doubInt yes, no problem! I've set the name to keep clearer, the indexes could be confusing sometimes, I don't know if it has any effect on performance.

Comment: It can be confuse? really, maybe I should do some research to find out

Answer (score 1):

You need to count all Group 1, 2 and 3 capture group values that are not empty:

```
var s = "There are many kids in the playground. It's about 1 23  45 5;中文等等";
var pattern = @"([0-9])|([a-zA-Z])|([\u4e00-\u9fa5])";
var ms = Regex.Matches(s, pattern).Cast<Match>();
var ascii_digit_cnt = ms.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).Count();
var ascii_letter_cnt = ms.Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).Count();
var han_cnt = ms.Select(x => x.Groups[3].Value).Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).Count();
Console.WriteLine($"{ascii_digit_cnt} : {ascii_letter_cnt} : {han_cnt}");
// => 6 : 39 : 4
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CdRpBF)

At first, you get all matches with `Regex.Matches(s, pattern).Cast<Match>()`. Then, you have ASCII digit matches in `x.Groups[1]`, ASCII letter matches in `x.Groups[2]` and Han chars in `x.Groups[3]`. The `.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)` removes all empty values (as those mean the group pattern did not match).